# Can't notify users after updating service worker (workbox, cra)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I'm trying to let user know that the app is updated after installing the new service worker.
But the problem is after doing the typical `skipWaiting()` and `ClientsClaim()` and trying to send message to clients that there is an update, `clients` array is empty.

index.js

```js
serviceWorkerRegistration.Register();
```

serviceWorkerRegistration.js

```js
function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === "installed") {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // here workbox sends message to service-worker.js
              registration.waiting.postMessage({ type: "SKIP_WAITING" });

              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Error during service worker registration:", error);
    });
}
```

service-worker.js

```js
self.addEventListener("message", event => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === "SKIP_WAITING") {
    skipWaiting();
    clientsClaim();
    //clients array is empty here
    self.clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
       clients.forEach(client => {
        client.postMessage("reload-window");
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Clients array is empty in `service-worker.js`, That being the case, I can't communicate with user.

(I've also setup notifications with this service worker, Clients array is not empty there as  a result I've no problem communicating with user)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the problem.

Should've been doing this part:

```js
self.clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
       clients.forEach(client => {
        client.postMessage("reload-window");
      });
    });
```

while listening to `activate` event like this:

```js
self.addEventListener("activate", () => {
  self.clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
    clients.forEach(client => {
      client.postMessage("reload-window");
    });
  });
});
```